# react navigation - DrawerNavigator for Header Menu icon inside TabNavigator-> StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I want to display HeaderLeft Menu icon globally in all screens. When I click on Menu Icon, I need to display Drawer Menu. I use "OpenDrawer", "CloseDrawer" methods for open/close drawer menu.

But I am always getting "`undefined is not a function (evaluating 'props.navigation.openDrawer()')"`. I also tried the following

```
props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())
props.navigation.navigate(openDrawer())
```

But None of the above worked. Here is my partial code

```
const MenuButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())} }>
        <Text>Menu</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
};

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Wishist: {
      screen: wishlist
    },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: SideMenuScreen,
    drawerWidth: 200,
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: createStackNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: Home
      },
      Contact: {
        screen: Contact
      }
    },
    {
      defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderWidth:0,
          borderBottomWidth:0
        },
        headerTitle: headerTitleNavigationOptions('HOME'),
        headerLeft: <MenuButton navigation={navigation}/>,
        headerRight: headerRightNavigatorOptions(navigation)
      })
    }),
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderWidth:0,
          borderBottomWidth:0
      },
    }),
  }},
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      showLabel: false,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderTopWidth:1
      }
    },
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: You're sending the "navigation" directly to MenuButton. Try replace this "props.navigation.openDrawer()" with this "navigation.openDrawer()"

Comment: Can't see `MyDrawerNavigator` declared in your main `AppNavigator`. Try making your drawerNavigator as your app container.

Answer (score 3):

you need to import the `DrawerActions` in your component from `react-navigation-drawer` [as explained in the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-actions.html)

> DrawerActions is an object containing methods for generating actions specific to drawer-based navigators. Its methods expand upon the actions available in NavigationActions.
>
> The following actions are supported:

- `openDrawer` - open the drawer
- `closeDrawer` - close the drawer
- `toggleDrawer` - toggle the state, ie. switche from closed to open and
  vice versa

---

```
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())
```

The `react-navigation` api do not provide more information, but you can consult [the `NavigationActions` api reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html) for more information.

## NavigationActions reference

> All `NavigationActions` return an object that can be sent to the router using `navigation.dispatch()` method.
>
> Note that if you want to dispatch `react-navigation` actions you should use the action creators provided in this library.

You need to import `NavigationActions` in your component and then you can `dispatch` your action with something like `this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);`

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'Profile',

  params: {},

  action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SubProfileRoute' }),
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

also as explained from [Ashwin Mothilal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5591671/ashwin-mothilal), make sure you are passing the `navigation` prop inside your component. For example you can run a `console.warn(props)` and immediatly see the result on the emulator.
This is your component:

```
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

const MenuButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          console.warn(props);
          props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
      }}>
        <Text>Menu</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
};
```

Comment: Inside MenuButton, the 'props' doesn't have any drawer methods. Refer JSON below

Comment: {"navigation":{"state":{"routeName":"Home","key":"id-1559109520033-0"},"actions":{}}}

Answer (score 0):

At first, just console the props in Menu button and check if you get openDrawer or closeDrawer or any other method you are looking for then you can call it.